# PHP get all values from specific key from array+object

Tags: php, recursion

I get an object like this from a SOAP web service:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["tasks"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (9) {
      ["externalId"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "Customer A"
      ["description"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["bookable"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["billable"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["subtasks"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#4 (9) {
          ["externalId"]=>
          string(1) "2"
          ["name"]=>
          string(5) "Job 1"
          ["description"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["bookable"]=>
          bool(true)
          ["billable"]=>
          bool(true)
          ["subtasks"]=>
          object(stdClass)#5 (9) {
            ["externalId"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["name"]=>
            string(7) "Job 1.1"
            ["description"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["bookable"]=>
            bool(true)
            ["billable"]=>
            bool(true)
            ["subtasks"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=>
              object(stdClass)#6 (8) {
                ["externalId"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["name"]=>
                string(9) "Job 1.1.1"
                ["description"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["bookable"]=>
                bool(true)
                ["billable"]=>
                bool(true)
                ["customField1"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["customField2"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["customField3"]=>
                string(0) ""
              }
              [1]=>
              object(stdClass)#7 (8) {
                ["externalId"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["name"]=>
                string(9) "Job 1.1.2"
                ["description"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["bookable"]=>
                bool(true)
                ["billable"]=>
                bool(true)
                ["customField1"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["customField2"]=>
                string(0) ""
                ["customField3"]=>
                string(0) ""
              }
            }
            ["customField1"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["customField2"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["customField3"]=>
            string(0) ""
          }
          ["customField1"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["customField2"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["customField3"]=>
          string(0) ""
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#8 (9) {
          ["externalId"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["name"]=>
          string(5) "Job 2"
          ["description"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["bookable"]=>
          bool(true)
          ["billable"]=>
          bool(true)
          ["subtasks"]=>
          object(stdClass)#9 (8) {
            ["externalId"]=>
            string(2) "55"
            ["name"]=>
            string(7) "Job 2.1"
            ["description"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["bookable"]=>
            bool(true)
            ["billable"]=>
            bool(true)
            ["customField1"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["customField2"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["customField3"]=>
            string(0) ""
          }
          ["customField1"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["customField2"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["customField3"]=>
          string(0) ""
        }
      }
      ["customField1"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["customField2"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["customField3"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#10 (8) {
      ["externalId"]=>
      string(3) "123"
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "Customer B"
      ["description"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["bookable"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["billable"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["customField1"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["customField2"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["customField3"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#11 (9) {
      ["externalId"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "Customer C"
      ["description"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["bookable"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["billable"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["subtasks"]=>
      object(stdClass)#12 (8) {
        ["externalId"]=>
        string(3) "918"
        ["name"]=>
        string(5) "Job 1"
        ["description"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["bookable"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["billable"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["customField1"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["customField2"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["customField3"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["customField1"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["customField2"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["customField3"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
  }
}
```

I need only a stupid function to check every element of externalId.

```
if( ["externalId"] != "")
{
   echo "value found! ".["externalId"]."<br>";
}
```

I tried to use `array_walk_recursive` but the object is a mix of arrays and objects.

Compare the ["subtasks"]-elements... 
Also tried SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS in the SOAP-call with no difference.
Is there some "magic"? I think the solution is pretty simple, but don't get it yet :-(

Keep in mind: there is no limit of recursively level - every ["subtasks"] can contains more ["subtasks"].

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

/**
 * @param \stdClass $root
 *
 * @return array
 */
function externalIdentifiersFrom(\stdClass $root)
{
    static $properties = [
        'tasks',
        'subtasks',
    ];

    $identifiers = [];

    if (property_exists($root, 'externalId')
        && is_string($root->externalId)
        && '' !== trim($root->externalId)
    ) {
        $identifiers[] = $root->externalId;
    }

    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        if (property_exists($root, $property) && is_array($root->{$property})) {
            $objects = $root->{$property};

            foreach ($objects as $object) {
                if (!$object instanceof \stdClass) {
                    continue;
                }

                $identifiers = array_merge(
                    $identifiers,
                    externalIdentifiersFrom($object)
                );
            }
        }
    }

    return array_unique($identifiers);
}

var_dump(externalIdentifiersFrom($object));
```